# jQuery plugins external functions

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am building my first jQuery plugin, a slideshow. It's working fine, I can pass as parameters, the direction, the interval and speed at which the images move.
Now I want to add a start and a stop function, to create or destroy the

```
obj = window.setInterval()
```

I use to change the images, so I can access those functions outside like:

```
slideshow = $('#slideshowstrip').slideshow();
slideshow.start();
slideshow.stop();
```

Comment: Is this a question? What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: i want to have built in functions in my plugin, for start and stop, and i don't know how to declare those functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might consider writing the plugin as a jQuery UI widget, using [the widget factory](http://docs.jquery.com/UI_Developer_Guide#The_widget_factory).

With a widget, you can easily add multiple functions:

```
$.widget("ui.slideshow", {
    options: {
        timer: false,
        interval: 1000
    },
    _init: function(){
        this.start();
    },
    start: function(){
        this.options.timer = setInterval(function(){}, this.options.interval);
    },
    stop: function(){
        if (this.options.timer) {
            clearInterval(this.options.timer);
            this.options.timer = false;
        }
    }
});
```

You can then call these functions like so:
`$("#pictures").slideshow("stop");`

Comment: yes, but if you don't need any of the other widgets or components of jQuery UI, I'm pretty sure you can just include the widget factory by itself, which amounts to ~4 KB, before compression.  (http://jqueryui.com/download, click "deselect all components", and then select "widget" under "UI Core".)

Comment: thank you, that did the trick, i had to learn a lot of new things, but it is done :)

Comment: excellent!  it's definitely worth the effort to learn how to make widgets... I only recently started using them myself, and they've greatly simplified some of my larger projects.